# Check if dictionary is equal that contains a class in one key

Tags: python

This started out as a different question, but I realised that `class == class` returns `False`. I read that you can use `type(class) == type(class)`, but I'm wondering if there would be a cleaner way to do this.

I can't copy over the exact code since it's got bits getting to this stage all over the place, but here is an example of what is happening:

```
a = self.data['test']['Frames']
b = self._original_data['test']['Frames']
print a == b
print str(a) == str(b)
```

Which results in:

```
defaultdict(<class '__main__._MovementInfo'>, {0: _MovementInfo(location=None, rotation=None, scale=None, visibility=None), 10: _MovementInfo(location=None, rotation=None, scale=None, visibility=None)})
defaultdict(<class '__main__._MovementInfo'>, {0: _MovementInfo(location=None, rotation=None, scale=None, visibility=None), 10: _MovementInfo(location=None, rotation=None, scale=None, visibility=None)})
False
True
```

I want to compare `self.data` to `self._original_data` which have a lot more values, so I'm wondering if I can do it all at once without having to break apart the `defaultdict`.

Here is an example of one value in `sorted(self.data.iteritems(), key=lambda (x, y): y['ListOrder'])`, which I sorted like that to always return the keys in the same order (there's a bug with 0.0 but it's not causing problems):

```
[('test', {'FrameDistance': -0.0, 'RandomOffset': -0.0, 'ListOrder': 0, 'FrameOffset': -0.0, 'ObjectSelection': set([]), 'ObjectOrigin': (-0.0, -0.0, -0.0), 'Frames': defaultdict(<class '__main__._MovementInfo'>, {0: _MovementInfo(location=None, rotation=None, scale=None, visibility=None), 10: _MovementInfo(location=None, rotation=None, scale=None, visibility=None)}), 'Axis': (False, False, False), 'BounceDistance': -0.0})
```

Is there a way of doing this properly, or should I convert it to a string?

Comment: Do you implement `__eq__` on the `_MovementInfo` instances?

Comment: Are you trying to check if all the key and values in `self.data` are in `self._original_data`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to check if everything is the same, though obviously the class stored as the default one in defaultdict is causing the problem. I haven't used `__eq__` before but I'll give it a shot, hopefully that should do the trick, cheers :)

Comment: Yeah thanks, using `__eq__` did the trick, if you put it as an answer I'll accept it